# Commerce 2: Custom product fields not showing up in order

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2, products

I've created a dropdown field for my users to select from on each of my products, but if the user was to select an option from the dropdown and click 'add to cart' , it doesn't show up in their order once it's all gone through.

What I currently have on my products page is:

```
<form method="POST" name="main">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/cart/update-cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="paymentCurrency" value="{{ currency }}">

    {{ redirectInput('cart') }}
    <input type="hidden" name="qty" value="1">
    {{ csrfInput() }}

    {% set max = product.max %} 
    {% set i = 0 %}

    <select name="options[max]">
        {% for i in 1..max %}
            <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
        {% endfor %} 
    </select>

    {%- for purchasable in product.getVariants() -%}
        {% if purchasable.isAvailable %}
            <input type="hidden" name="purchasables[0][id]" value="{{ purchasable.id }}" />
            <input type="hidden" name="purchasables[0][qty]" value="1" />
        {% endif %}
    {%- endfor -%}

    {%- for purchasable in product.getVariants() -%}
        {{ purchasable|currencySalePrice('' ~ currency ~ '') }}
    {%- endfor -%}

    <input type="submit" value="{{ "Add to cart"|t }}" class="button"/>
</form>
```

Any reason why 'add to cart' wouldn't update this info and show it in the customers order?

Comment: Could you paste your full form?

Comment: Updated with form

Answer (score 1):

First you need to figure out which one you are using.

**LineItem Options:**
Here is the doc for it. 
https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/v2/adding-to-and-updating-the-cart.html#line-item-options-and-notes

One thing worth to mention is that options store in lineItem, which is one set of options for each purchasable/variant. So in your form you should put the options in your for loop of the `product.getVariants()`.
And have the loop index in front just like the purchasable. e.g.

```
<select name="options[0][max]">
        {% for i in 1..max %}
            <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
        {% endfor %} 
</select>
```

Same with your "qty" it needs to have loop index in front as well.
See the documentation link for example: 
https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/v2/adding-to-and-updating-the-cart.html#adding-multiple-purchasables-to-the-cart

**Order Field:**
Didn't find documentation for it in craft CMS commerce 2 docs.
Order field stores with order object. One order has one value for a unique field handle. 
You can use `<input type="your-choice" name="fields[customFieldHandle]"/>` in "commerce/cart/update-cart" action.
You can retrieve it by calling `order.customFieldHandle`.

Before you use one custom field in the twig template you need to go your control panel and create a custom field first. "http://your-site.com/admin/commerce/settings/ordersettings". Find the "order fields" (name maybe different due to the version of craft, I don't think P&T have ever changed it since beginning.) tab, and create a field just like you would create a field for entry.

**Try this form:**

```
<form method="POST" name="main">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/cart/update-cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="paymentCurrency" value="{{ currency }}">

    {{ redirectInput('cart') }}
    {{ csrfInput() }}

    {% set max = product.max %}

    {%- for purchasable in product.getVariants() -%}
        {% if purchasable.isAvailable %}
            <input type="hidden" name="purchasables[{{loop.index}}][id]" value="{{ purchasable.id }}" />
            <select name="options[{{loop.index}}][max]">
             {% for i in 1..max %}
                <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
             {% endfor %} 
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" name="purchasables[{{loop.index}}][qty]" value="1"/>
        {% endif %}
    {%- endfor -%}

    {%- for purchasable in product.getVariants() -%}
        {{ purchasable|currencySalePrice('' ~ currency ~ '') }}
    {%- endfor -%}

    <input type="submit" value="{{ "Add to cart"|t }}" class="button"/>
</form>
```

If you want customer to choose one options and apply for all the purchasables.

Just put a hidden input in the for loop and then use JavaScript function to update options in the loop on change.

Comment: the qty how it is is intentional, I did try your version of the select and it still hasn't worked. I find that this only works when I add an additional 'update' button, but I really want to avoid doing.

Comment: Try the form I just posted.

Comment: afraid this didn't work either :/

Comment: Can you try to add to cart again? And take a look at the storage/logs/web.log. Search for the unique value of the product/purchasable you just try add to cart. See if you can find any error.

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary in the logs, which made me think it's not doing anything with the custom field.